# setting up hardware site to site vpn connection using one customer gateway to multiple vpcs

Tags: vpn, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

so we have 4 vpc's but have to connect them to our on premise office and set up vpn connection between them as i can create only one customer gateway because we have only one public ip address for our network, it is not letting me create another cg it says duplicate ip exists in another cg, what am i supposed to do, can we connect different vpg to single cg is it possible, how to connect our four vpc's to our network and establish hardware site to site vpn connectivity

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/NetworkAdminGuide/Introduction.html):

> You can create additional VPN connections to other VPCs using the same
>   customer gateway device. You can reuse the same customer gateway IP
>   address for each of those VPN connections.

Comment: Multiple VPCs in the same region cannot be connected with the same remote IPSec device. AWS doesn’t allow two connections within the same region to be connected to the same “Customer Gateway” (even when using multiple accounts).                                                                                   can you please take a look at this http://fortycloud.com/aws-virtual-private-gateway/                                 I am confused looking at this